# I would like to highlight the background of a cell based on a text from another column

Tags: excel, vba

as said above, i would like to highlight the background of certain cells from another column based on the text that is on the "example" picture
for example :
if the text is "Run" it highlights the cell as green

open for any other ways to do it

will reply to any questions
thank you for your time

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHzzP.png)

Comment: You can see this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this. Conditional formatting using a simple formula will work.

Answer (score 1):

[This URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) explains how conditional formatting can do this.

The question is, why did you opt for VBA for doing this:

- You were not aware of conditional formatting.
- You only want this do be done, based on a certain action (clicking a button).

In the second case, highlighting can be done as follows (based on a selected cell):

```
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: i choose vba because when i searched for this, the conditional formatting examples were only using 1 column and not another value to condition the color of another one

Comment: Oh, in that case I would definitely recommend conditional formatting: it can be used over different cells, even over different worksheets.

Comment: i will give it a search, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Cells

- The following assumes that the `A` column contains the criteria (`Run`) and the `B` column is formatted. Adjust this to fit your needs.

**Excel**

In e.g. cell `B2` use the conditional formatting rule (`Use a formula to determine which cells to format`)...

```
=A2="Run"
```

... and copy down.

**VBA**

- Adjust the values in the constants section and the worksheet (Something like `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` is preferred (safer).).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightCells()
    
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    Const sFirst As Long = 2
    Const sCriteria As String = "Run"
    
    Const dCol As String = "B"
    Const dColor As Long = vbGreen
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim sLast As Long: sLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If sLast < sFirst Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sString As String
    
    For r = sFirst To sLast
        sString = CStr(ws.Cells(r, sCol).Value)
        If sString = sCriteria Then
            ws.Cells(r, dCol).Interior.Color = dColor
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

**Conditional Formatting in VBA**

(a third option)